# Inserting into database without click event ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, events

I'm trying to insert data into database without using click event.
I have few controls on form and after writing in them I want to get values into database automatically without clicking.

What are the possible ways to do this when you using ASP.NET?

I was thinking using onfocus event, but as I know onfocus doesn't support focus on multiple controls at the same time. Is someone has a better suggestion for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use some sort of two-way binding via Angular or Knockout.  Every time the model changes, save the entire model to the database.  That said, this seems like a terrible idea.  You'll be hitting the db far more often than it seems like you would need to and it'll make validation a bit more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah I do think the same way too. It is stupid and horrible idea to me too. Database could be a total mess inserting this way, but that is my assignment and I have to deal with it. I will look up little bit more about your suggestions :) @DavidL

Comment: Understandable :).  We all have those types of tasks.  Good luck!

Comment: I've had a similar project, I used Ajax + Webservices. it should do the trick, that way you can use plain html controls and don't necessarily need to use Asp.net Controls